# Synonymize [ahk] with [autohotkey]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[ahk](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ahk) should probably be a synonym of [autohotkey](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/autohotkey)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
updating post history, 3 rows affected
updating posts, 2 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 1 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [autohotkey] and [ahk] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
3 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
Tag Synonym ahk -> autohotkey was approved!
```

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)